# Load json file with arrays /structs and flexible schema into Hive table

Tags: arrays, json, struct, hive, load

Need some help loading a json file into a table . Here is an example of some of the json objects within the file:

```
{"asin": "0002000202", "title": "Black Berry, Sweet Juice: On Being Black and White in Canada", "price": 13.88, "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51PQAYJ9EDL.jpg", "related": {"also_bought": ["0393333094"], "buy_after_viewing": ["0393333094", "1554685087"]}, "salesRank": {"Books": 3013713}, "categories": [["Books"]]}
{"asin": "0000041696", "title": "Arithmetic 2 A Beka Abeka 1994 Student Book (Traditional Arithmentic Series)", "price": 6.53, "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41cGaan-BrL._SL500_.jpg", "related": {"also_viewed": ["B000KOYDUY", "B004GE1B7W", "B008SXBO88", "B001EH7Y02", "B000W7PN62", "B004H3G1X6", "B004WOEIXA", "B000AXWEEM", "0789478722", "B000MN2C56", "1402709269", "B001HHOKG0", "B000Y9TO1S", "1402711441", "0756609356", "0142400106", "1556616465", "0545021383", "B004LDD18A", "B000HZH18C", "1557996563", "B00CZTVUKI", "B001CXK8Y2", "B000QX6KY6"], "buy_after_viewing": ["B000KOYDUY", "B004GE1B7W", "B000LBXGRC", "0439827655"]}, "salesRank": {"Books": 2554321}, "categories": [["Books"]]}
```

As you can see the schema varies among objects. Some not all attributes are present in all objects. There are also structs and arrays.

Here is my create table statement

```
create table amazon.products_test
(asin string,
title string,
description string,
brand string,
price float,
salesRank struct<category:string, rank:int> ,
imUrl string,
categories array<string>,
related struct<also_bought:string, also_viewed:string, buy_after_viewing:string, bought_together:string>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe';
```

My load statement:

```
load data inpath '/user/amazon/products_test.json'
overwrite into table amazon.products_test;
```

Here I try and query

```
hive> select * FROM products_test;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.IOException: Field name expected
```

Do I have the right datatypes ?
Is there a better serde ?
Do I need add TBLPROPERTIES  or SERDEPROPERTIES ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer . As suspected, I needed to use a different SERDE:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
```

I saw some forums suggesting that I may need to use this SERDE but I didn't know how to implement and add the jars from :

https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

- also , I needed to use a map map type not a struct for the salesRank